# Python3 string wrong encoding

Tags: python, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am retrieving data from Oracle Database. In the database there is a column in a table that contains bad encoded characters like these: �

I am trying to retrieve this info in Python and convert the string to the correct encoding, however, I don't really know how to do this.

Let's say I have this string, Is there any Python module that can properly encode this string.

```
string = "�C: TH limit to 1"
```

The correct original encoding of this string was windows-1252 if it helps.

If it is not possible to encode this string properly in Python, is there any way to do this in Oracle Database?

This problem was caused because a file was read in C# with incorrect encoding, and later this data was inserted to the database with incorrect encoding.

Comment: What version of cx_Oracle and what `encoding` parameter did you use during connection, if any?  Or did you set NLS_LANG?  Check the cx_Oracle manual - recent versions have changed the defaults.  https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/globalization.html

Comment: @ChristopherJones I think the problem is because a c# code readed a file with incorrect encoding, and insert it to the database with incorrect encoding. So now in the database the data is displayed with bad encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the encoding of the string:

```py
string.encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: This returns `b'\xef\xbf\xbdC: TH limit to 1'`which isn't the correct string.

Comment: Ah ok, hang on, let me try another use case. Before I get ahead of myself, I would say it's safe to conclude you're going to need to do this on the Oracle side.

Comment: This problem was caused because a file was read in C# with incorrect encoding, and later this data was inserted to the database with incorrect encoding.

Comment: Ah, that'll do it. Awesome you figured it out!